# How to send pdf data and save from SQL Server using python(server) and Angular (client)

Tags: python, angular

I have my REST application.

Client side -> Angular 5.

Server side -> python (using cherrypy).

Database -> SQL Server.

Database screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHGE.png)

I want to click button and download a file to my computer. What is the best way to download this file from database?

Python:

```
with CDN_XL:
        CDN_XL.executeWithParams("""SELECT DAB_Dane FROM CDN.DaneBinarne, CDN.DaneObiekty WHERE DAB_ID = DAO_DABId AND DAB_ID = %s""", (download_id))
        CDN_XL.conn.commit()
        types = CDN_XL.cur.fetchall()
        information_json = []
        if types is not None and len(types) > 0:
            for typ in types:
              information_json.append({"data": str(typ["DAB_Dane"])})

            output_json = {"files":information_json}
            return json.dumps(output_json, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I return this to client, but i know this is not correct. It was my first idea.

Angular:

```
public downloadAttachments(id, idAttachment) {
  const requestUrl = this.firmListBaseUrl + id + '/ZALACZNIKI/' + idAttachment + '/' + idAttachment;
  return this.http.get(requestUrl, { headers: this.sharedServicesService.prepareAuthHeaders() })
  .map(res => {
    return res.json().files;
  });
```

}

Now I am trying to convert somehow this data to Blob and save as pdf. 
I guesse is not correct so I decided to write here for help. Thanks!

Comment: Kindly show what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the data in your db already as binary.

```
with CDN_XL:
        CDN_XL.executeWithParams("""SELECT DAB_Dane FROM CDN.DaneBinarne, CDN.DaneObiekty WHERE DAB_ID = DAO_DABId AND DAB_ID = %s""", (download_id))
        CDN_XL.conn.commit()
        pdf_bin = CDN_XL.cur.fetchone() 

        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename="report.pdf"'
        return pdf_bin["DAB_Dane"]
```

*Ps. I'm a django guy. My cherrypi-foo is not very strong*

Comment: @Iggsy Hum, depends what you're really trying to do. My guess is you want to give the client the PDF, NOT the data. Do you want do display it inline or do you just want the client to download it? Either way, a rest api returning the pdf binary data is a bad idea. Have your rest just return the content and dont try to wrap it inside a dictionary.

Comment: I want to give the PDF to client, this is the main goal (to download it).

Comment: @Iggsy also. Returning multiple pdf's at once.. is pretty wasteful, thats a log of data being transmitted that the client might not ever see. Simplify your RESt view, to have a single be returned. If the client wants more, let the client request more, don't interpret what the client _might_ want

Comment: Ok, I have now my data but with ����. What should I do in client side application?

Comment: @Iggsy thats because something is encoding it as a string, it shouldnt be -- it should be *bytes*. Maybe its the way its being stored? It should be a blob. You can try: `pdf_bin["DAB_Dane"].encode()`

Comment: @Iggsy hit the URL directly with the browser, not with JS. See if the page loads. What we've done is more of the: direct link  on a good old `<a>`tag, and not a ajax call. Take a picture if you must

Comment: Now I have different problem : "You are not authorized to access that resource" when i tried to open this.

Comment: @Iggsy use chrome/firefox, open the dev panel, open the "Network" tab, identify the call, right-click and select "Open in New Tab"

Comment: 401, "You are not authorized to access that resource")
cherrypy._cperror.HTTPError: (401, 'You are not authorized to access that resource')

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. I have my result.